# What can be the reasons or advantages for Russia's candid admission of their own fighter dropping ordnance over Belgorod instead of blaming Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Today, [a report](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/21/world/asia/russia-belgorod-bomb.html) came up about a Russian attack aircraft dropping ordnance over Belgorod, causing a crater 40m wide in one of the central streets of the city. Some reports indicate that this was an accidental weapons release, and the Russian Ministry of Defence stated that an investigation is underway.

In the current Russia invasion of Ukraine, the information war has been more important than ever, with both sides constantly trying to wrestle the truth to make it fit their own narrative, to rally both foreign and local receptors to their side.

I am wondering - considering the situation, and the previous instances of back-and-forth blaming for different actions like [cross-border attacks on Russia](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/2/russia-accuses-ukraine-of-cross-border-attack-in-bryansk), [intention of nuclear attacks](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-accuses-kyiv-planning-stage-nuclear-incident-2023-02-19), or even [the nord stream pipeline explosion](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-63044747) - what would prompt Russia to directly admit to a mishap in such an incident?

It seems that it would be easier to blame the attack in Ukraine, considering the current state of affairs and the obvious convenience of the Russian government to rally their population behind them to increase the war support, **why would they admit to an obvious blunder? Does this offer political advantages of any sort?**

I can only think that NATO AWACS are able to identify which aircraft were in the vicinity of the city when the explosion happened, and western countries could use that information to counter the Russian narrative, should they decide to accuse e.g. Ukraine, but it would not seem anything too different from the information/disinformation campaigns we have already experienced.

---

**UPDATE**: As of 2023-04-23, [two more unexploded ordnance were found](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/04/22/europe/russia-belgorod-accident-bomb-found-intl/index.html) in Belgorod coming from the same aircraft, giving more weight to the hypothesis of an accidental/deliberate emergency jettison, with maybe one of the bombs going off accidentally.

Comment: "the information war has been more important than ever" Not on the ground really. For over a year now bomb shells kill people in Ukraine. Not sure how important the information campaigns really are. This may be its own question.

Comment: I think that this boils down to one thing. The truth will come out eventually, and so it's better to admit to the truth than to lie about it and be caught out lying.

Comment: In the real world no one is like the lying guards in the twoo-door riddle who are compelled to lie even if it is detrimental to them. So why is it so strange for them to admit a mistake, especially if 1. it is a mistake occasionally made by any other military, including the US one, and 2. it would be trivial to disprove them if they tried to lie about it.

Comment: The main assumption(s) here is that the Russian government has a vice-like grip on the media and can supress any story they choose, and that the government is a totalitarian dictatorship that suppresses any unfavourably story. These simply aren't true.

Comment: @Valorum: when it comes to contracting the official MoD line, one can be sent to prison in Russia for that [IIRC for up to 5 years] for "discrediting" it. (About 5,800 cases opened thus far https://english.alarabiya.net/News/world/2023/03/01/Russian-law-amendments-punish-discrediting-military-including-voluntary-formations) So, it's not like with other stories, had the MoD decided to cover this up. (But given the 2nd, unexploded bomb, that would have been difficult--see my answer.)

Comment: @Trilarion shells also kill people in Russia, in the disputed territories, and a few casualties have occurred across the border if you were not aware...

Comment: @fabspro You're right, although most people by far die in Ukraine in this war. I guess that for them the matter is clear (of who is responsible). The information-war is more for the bystanders in the rest of the world, judging who is more brutal than the other or whatever this is good for.

Comment: *Information war* does not mean necessarily lying all the time. Here the Russian army boosts its own credibility by admitting its own mishap, which produced little damage, and would be hard to deny.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think either Russian or Ukraine care about what bystanders think. Information war matters as far as it comes a) keeping one's own army fighting, b) keeping people believing in their government policy, c) assuring political and financial support from abroad. Public opinion of *bystanders* matters only as much as these bystanders vote and elect politicians favoring this or that policy.

Comment: @Trilarion to be honest, my own experiences have been that Ukraine has fought much more of an information war. Thinking back five or six years ago, Ukrainians were editing StackExchange travel questions and answers to rename cities from their English names to Ukrainian ones. Western society doesn't usually appreciate people going around spreading propaganda and trying to 'correct' language (or for that matter, rename countries like Burma, Turkey etc), and at the time I felt it was very odd to have people 'policing' language. Ah what a world we live in now.

Comment: @fabspro Judging from a single example about who is more interested in something like information war is questionable. Russia for example has a long tradition of not telling the truth. Also, the old saying that everything was better in the past, often is not backed up. People just say that information war is more important but is it really? That's a much more difficult question. For example, this incident here is just about two bombs out of hundreds of thousands that will have been used in the war. How important is it to ask about that?

Comment: @Trilarion I am free to judge the world through my own experiences - it is a core tenet of western life called individualism. Yes, Russia and Ukraine have a long history of being dishonest and even being the west's enemy during a period known as the cold war. My subsequent observations have included Ukrainians policing language on Q&A websites, and actually a car accident where the other driver was Ukrainian, who made a fraudulent insurance claim which had to be resolved by a Court. I have no experience with bombs, but I know I can't rely on information from your country or its citizens!

Comment: @fabspro Of course you can do whatever you want. Just wanted to point out that typically anecdotal evidence isn't regarded as convincing argument. If you would want to convince somebody of something (probably you didn't want to anyway) you would need to conduct a thorough investigation and do statistics and describe your methodology. And even then you wouldn't convince many because many people don't want to be convinced. That's just how it is. Been there myself.

Comment: @Trilarion well, it's not anecdotal evidence, it's my actual experience - the only time I've ever been defrauded after a motor accident was by a Ukrainian physicist with a PhD...

Comment: @fabspro Your actual experience is still only anecdotal evidence. Not sure why you seem to think different.

Comment: @Trilarion if you have some academic studies for me to view, i'm happy to review it and be persuaded, otherwise i'll be relying on my own experience above a stranger on the internet. I'm not here to persuade others of anything, just sharing what happened to me. :)

Comment: @fabspro I currently don't have the time for searching for studies. Maybe others have. This site is not a forum for sharing experiences. Just imagine everyone would post their experiences. There would be thousands of comments spamming the site.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Kremlin admitted the fact that it was Russia that bombed its own city, because if they blame Ukraine for the bombing, the Russian population will question the efficacy of the Russian air defense systems.

**References:**

> Об этом сказал советник главы Офиса президента Михаил Подоляк в эфире телемарафона, сообщает РБК-Украина в пятницу, 21 апреля. ... "Они посчитали риски. Если они скажут, что Украина атаковала – тогда это существенно деморализует дополнительно. Тогда в России начнут говорить, а где же ПВО? Они тогда будут понимать, что Россия не защищена", – сказал Подоляк.

> This was mentioned by the advisor to the head of the Office of the President Mykhailo Podolyak during telethon, as reported by RBK-Ukraine on Friday, April 21. ... They [The Kremlin] calculated the risks. If they say that Ukraine carried out the attack, then this will demoralize [the Russian population] even more. Then in Russia they will start talking: where is the air defense? They will start to understand that Russia is not protected.

*Konstantin Katyshev "The Office of the President explained why Russia admitted the strike on Belgorod". Korrespondent.net, April 21, 2023: https://korrespondent.net/ukraine/4583030-v-op-poiasnyly-pochemu-rossyia-pryznala-udar-po-belhorodu*

The same quote appears [here](https://nv.ua/world/countries/belgorod-20-aprelya-kakuyu-bombu-sbrosil-rossiyskiy-su-34-na-gorod-foto-video-poslednie-novosti-50319273.html).

Comment: “People, don't worry! Our military is superior, nothing could ever breach our defenses! Anybody trying would get blown into smithereens! We missile any enemy plane and shoot any enemy tank and carpet-bomb any enemy spy who has made it into our cities!”

Comment: Plot twist: it was *actually* the Ukrainians?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Also the enemy can't bomb our cites and kill our civilians, so we have to do it for them;-)

Comment: BTW the logic is very similar to the case of sinking of Moskva: everybody knows it was hit by a Ukrainian attack, but the Kremlin insists on something else.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the reasoning that it would akin to admit weakness against Ukraine, some other motives come from the nature of the incident:

- It was an accident, which meant that it was unexpected (duh!). The Russian government did not have time to prepare an accusation against Ukraine. Typically, if the government was to accuse Ukraine, it would not just say "It was Ukraine" but also provide details ("we detected an aircraft flying from this Ukrainian airbase at this time that followed that route...") and "evidence". There was no time to prepare such a story.
- Also because it was an accident, it is to be expected that at the moment there were lots of communications between the parties involved (the pilots, the airbase, the civil defense authorities) before it could be curtailed and censored. So probably some of those communications have been recorded, and a relatively large amount of people could know the truth.

Both of those made a vague accusation against Ukraine quite risky, as the Russian government did not know what evidence could be out there refuting its claims. So pressing the accusations carried the risk of ending with a loss of credibility for the Russian government.

Answer (score 19):

The whole incident happened on a busy street, which means there were a lot of witnesses that could testify the origin of the blast was an explosive fired from a fighter jet. That would imply two things:

1. Ukraine has operational fighter jets.
2. These aircraft can enter Russian airspace.

Not a good message to send. Instead, if the Russian military admits it was their own jet, they can mantain to have absolute control over their own airspace, and even air superiority anywhere in the war theater.

Comment: That kind of fits with the given explanation for the sinking of the cruiser Moskva back in April 2022. It was during strong winds and heavy sea (only it wasn't) not just because of Ukrainian fire.

Comment: Well, the could have claimed it was a Ukrainian missile or GLSDB. Russia does regularly claim Belgorod markets are hit by mortar fire.

Comment: And they even claimed attacks with bigger weapons last summer https://tass.com/russia/1475005 "Kiev uses Tochka-U, Tu-143 drones on residential areas in Belgorod and Kursk"

Comment: @Fizz But the towns and villages along the border in the Belgorod region are indeed hit

Comment: @CITBL: In my own estimation, that's very likely true. I'm just saying here that "Russia doesn't want to acknowledge being hit, as that shows weakness" is probably not that compelling in this case/region [of Belgorod]. (Although there's the Moskva cruiser which argues in the opposite direction, in some [different perhaps] circumstances.)

Comment: Longer story summarizing other incidents in Belgorod region https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2023/02/24/on-russias-border-with-ukraine-war-is-impossible-to-ignore-a80303

Comment: The videos show this happened at night.  The witnesses on the street would not have "seen" anything.

Answer (score 11):

Russian pro-war commentators initially blamed Ukraine for the blast and questioned why Kyiv was able to launch an attack on the centre of Belgorod ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/apr/21/russian-plane-accidentally-strikes-russian-city-near-ukraine-border-leaving-20m-crater), The Guardian):

> Ukrainian special services show that they can blow up almost everything.

This may sound too much in the favor of the enemy. As there were no casualties (just three injured), it may be more beneficial to tell the truth if it really was an accidental discharge.

Comment: And even then, there was some room for "huh" moments in the official coverage. https://news.sky.com/video/ukraine-war-belgorod-bombing-highlights-the-incompetence-of-russian-pilots-12862708 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62bQ_7xoWKQ "modern weapons allow Russian units to eliminate extremists in the zone from a minimal distance."

Answer (score 5):

Another possible/additional explanation is that they knew (from the pilot) that in fact two (!) bombs had been dropped. And since only one went off, the other had to be somewhere in the city. It was located and defused about one-and-a-half days later. Covering up unexploded ordnance search would have been slightly more difficult, as would have been the op to dig it up and defuse it etc. (But I am somewhat speculating here since the details of this 2nd bomb have been a bit sketchy, at least in the Western press, besides the [evacuation](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65358070) it caused. Only photos I found of the latter were on Twitter, and [they](https://twitter.com/bayraktar_1love/status/1649735838337466368?cxt=HHwWgICwlaOAheUtAAAA) have a narrow field of view of the dig site. So I'm not sure how obvious this 2nd bomb's presence/location was a day before, to random passers by.) But once exposed intact, it would have been hard[er] to pretend it was a GLSDB or some other long-range Western weapon. And unless Belgorod had anti-air activation the night of the event (none was reported) it would have been both implausible and undesirable to claim a Ukrainian plane could have snuck in undetected and dropped a couple of FABs.

Finally, [according](https://youtu.be/TcyaFO4Sszc?t=139) to Western media, around the time of the Ukrainian offensive last year, a high-level decision was made to start admitting some failures. So we might also see a small reflection of that here as well. (This new communication paradigm came together with more calls for total war though.)

Comment: Upvoted - needing to dig up some bombs may very well have motivated this.  Things to keep in mind however:  a) they could have said their air defense radar "saw" multiple bombs drop - who's going to know/contradict?  b) you *have* to cordon off bomb disposal areas, making it easier to control info and c) the bomb in question is a std 500kg Soviet model.  Ukraine probably has some in its own fleet and... easy enough to lie about that anyway.  The, as you point out, non-activation of air defense radar probably is a factor.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: well, if they saw the bombs on radar, but not the plane... or if they saw the plane but didn't shoot it... it would look pretty bad. There was a low-level incursion from Ukr helos in that region last year though (prolly the kind you don't seen on radar). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F45FHLpKtI

Answer (score 4):

I must state an obvious thing which is left over by other answers:

Russian MoD understood that the word will get out, and they would look unreliable and (even more) untrustworthy. It is obviously better mid- and long-term to admit a mistake rather than much later be blamed for mistake and covering it up.

I believe it is possible that a year ago they would try the cover-up route, but seeing as the military action is quite transparent in the XXI century they were finally able to admit the reality that you can't cover up things like that.

There's a russian saying of `шила в мешке не утаишь` (literally "you cannot hide a stitching awl in a bag"), meaning some things cannot be hidden.

A comparable incident would be [UIA Flight 752](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine_International_Airlines_Flight_752) where Iran was comparatively quick at admitting that they have downed the civilian plane, rather than waiting and having somebody else stick it in their face.

Comment: There's probably some truth to this. Even Russians may come to notice TASS lies all the time if that's the only thing it does. While the answers based on "it would show incompetence in air defense" have *some* ring of truth, Russia acknowledged strikes on its [strategic air bomber airfields](https://tass.com/defense/1547947) last December. Which were then propagandized to ["terrorism"](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/three-killed-fuel-tanker-explosion-russian-airfield-2022-12-05/). So it could have been a clear benefit for RU to blame UA, *as long as the truth did not come to light.*

Comment: Russians do not watch TV that much and they're all on either WhatsApp or Telegram.

Comment: “шила в мешке не утаишь”, please explain the meaning in the answer.

Comment: @alamar, that's not _[quite](https://www.rbc.ru/technology_and_media/21/04/2023/644241819a794720778290aa)_ true: 4 hours/day average is not nothing (and obviously a lot more amongst 55+). Then, as we've learnt, propaganda and cover-up doesn't work (anymore) by offering a plausible counter-story, but rather by flooding with many different stories, however ridiculous and contradictory they are (cf. MH17). And Russians are well-versed in _doublethink_: they will be the first to acknowledge that "everybody lies", yet comfortably prefer the official line. Nevertheless, this is likely _a_ reason.

Comment: @Zeus I like how you demonstrated the "many different stories" approach.

Comment: @A.L: I added a translation. Feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

if Russia tried to claim this was a Ukrainian attach, they would be in effect stating that they could not prevent the Ukraine from attacking into Russia. In other words their defenses did not work.

Add to this embarrassment when the truth comes out that it was a Russian plane that dropped the bombs.

Comment: why would the first paragraph be a problem for them? They can use it to justify even more conscription, even more bombing, etc

Comment: They had no qualms claiming such prior attacks happened https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62025541 ; it's true that the one one with video footage of helos (in April last year) would have been harder to disguise as something else. But Russia also claimed [some of] these helos hit residential buildings https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-ukraine-fired-mortars-bryansk-border-post-2022-04-14/

Comment: @user253751 As coercive as Russian society is, they still need some compliance from the public on these things. "Look, we're too incompetent to protect our territory, but you should still let us take all your male children and everything will work out fine" does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score -2):

Bombs fall at an angle, not straight down. The fall angle is typically 25-45 degrees. The crater tends to have a steeper slope on the impact direction side. Bomb tail debris tends to fly in the opposite direction.

It's also possible that some witnesses in the city have heard the aircraft and the which direction it's been flying, north or south.

No point losing credibility on something so easily verified.

Comment: It happened at night, so somewhat hard to do "planespotting". Also, if you watched the video, the bomb had a pretty long delay fuse (seconds). The paper you've lined is about *impact* craters. That one was negligible here. (The low casualties are in fact because it exploded rather deep under the street, so there was little shrapnel. It was more like a demo charge.) And above all, anyone contradicting the Russian MoD can be sent to prison in Russia, for "discrediting" the armed forces.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/12tumex/explosion_of_yesterdays_bomb_that_russia_dropped/

Comment: In fact, the 2nd bomb (yeah, there were two), took like one-and-a-half days to find. Because it didn't explode and made such a small impact crater it was hard to find (approx. 250 meters from where first one fell.) Some reports even say this was found 7 meters underground, but I'm skeptical it went that deep, unless it fell in a sewer or somethig.

Comment: @Fizz the second bomb has really weird [implications](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79331/2984), indeed.

Comment: @Fizz The explosive crater also depends on the angle of impact, since the bomb will dig in more along its line of impact. I'll see if I find a paper that's specifically about bomb craters.

Comment: I do not follow the logic of "since it came from the NE it was a Russian bombers." Mostly because almost all of the airplanes that have been designed are able to turn while in flight (perhaps with a few exceptions like the Wright brothers' first prototypes). So an Ukrainian military airplane could certainly have made a small turn and approached Belgorod from a direction other than straight from Ukraine.

Comment: @SJuan76 Bombs can be released from as far as [100 km away](https://www.boeing.ca/products-and-services/defense-space-security/small-diameter-bomb.page), about 40 km realistically, so it's possible to bomb Belgorod without even exiting Ukraine's airspace. Doing a U-turn north of the city is a massive and pointless risk.

Comment: This question about the *motivation* for TASS not to lie is difficult to answer without insider knowledge.  Fancy diagrams about bomb flight paths don't add one bit to it, nor claims that bystanders would recognize a, possibly high/medium-altitude, plane in the midst of the night.  -1.

Answer (score -3):

### Because They Hit The City With Two Bombs

Which implies that the bombing was **intentional**.
And the Russian propaganda wants you to believe the bombing has happened **by accident**.

---

[image: the second russian bomb]
<sub>(image from [mil.in.ua](https://mil.in.ua/en/news/not-one-but-two-russian-bombs-fell-on-belgorod/))</sub>

> More than 3,000 people have been evacuated from their homes in the Russian city of Belgorod after an **undetonated explosive** was found. […] The undetonated device was found in the same area as the bomb that was accidentally dropped on Thursday evening — [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65358070)

> Russian media claim that the second bomb was discovered in the area of house №15 on Shalandina Street, **approximately 250 meters from the site** of the first bomb explosion. Presumably, this is a 500-kilogram FAB-500 high-explosive bomb. It damaged the balconies of a high-rise building, falling just a few meters away. The bomb buried itself in the ground next to the foundation to a depth of several meters and did not explode. — [mil.in.ua](https://mil.in.ua/en/news/not-one-but-two-russian-bombs-fell-on-belgorod/)

> The unexploded item is a general purpose air-dropped bomb designated **FAB-500**, reported Izvestia, a Russian publication. It added that the weapon, which weighs 500 kilogrammes (1,100 pounds), was discovered at a **depth of five metres**. — [RepublicWorld](https://www.republicworld.com/world-news/russia-ukraine-crisis/russia-explosive-found-in-belgorod-prompts-evacuation-of-3000-residents-articleshow.html)

---

So it is now easy to reproduce the logic of the Russian commandment and their propaganda:

- The construction of Su-34 aircraft does not allow to release *two ordnance at the same time*, even occasionally. Simply speaking, **you have to push the trigger twice**;
- Which implies that **the pilot had intent** to release two bombs;
- At the moment, there is no publicly available information about whether the pilot intentionally bombed Belgorod or was he thinking he is slaughtering another large city (e.g. Kharkiv).
- The Russian commandment had known about the fact at once. There is no chance they could have known about *the first* bomb and not about *the second* one.
- So they decided to insist on "bombing by accident" version in public media.

**A rule of thumb: if a clearly biased source seemingly admits a blunder, stay assured that the truth is even worse.**

Comment: ... so why not blame Ukraine for dropping two bombs?

Comment: @user253751 well, because no Ukrainian jets were tracked in the area? Or because there's abundance of SAT/intel information about the route of the offending aircraft? Or maybe because it is easy to track the serial# of the unexploded bomb? Or simply because [Ukraine does not operate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-34#Operators) Su-34's? Who knows…

Comment: what does any of that have to do with the fact there were two bombs instead of one?

Comment: @user253751 my comment was only to reply on your comment. If it were whatsoever relevant to my answer I would include it there.

Comment: "The construction of Su-34 aircraft does not allow to release two ordnance at the same time" -> SU-34 avionics don't allow the double-pickle release mode or releases based on distance, etc like western ones e.g. F-16, F-18, Eurofighter...? Have you got links on that as your premise hangs on it (genuine question)?

Comment: Why would Russia intentionally bomb its own city only to freely admit it later? Because it is not a false flag operation if you do not make it look like it was your enemy who performed it. There is nothing to gain by this. This just makes no sense.

Comment: @HaroldH if I understand correctly, you are talking about *salvo mode*. It takes more than a single button push to activate. Nevertheless, I'm going to find Su-34 operating manual for a solid proof.

Comment: @SJuan76 I think you misread the answer. I did not say that the Russian commandment *instructed* the pilots to bomb their own city. What I say is that it was either a pilots' mistake or pilots' intentional action. It is easy to figure out as soon as the Russian military court takes place. If we see the pilots (there are two of them) alive and happy (possibly in jail) then it was a mistake. If you never hear about them again then my logic is accurate. To me personally, the second bomb was the turning point in this mystery, but I agree it takes time to convince the others.

Comment: It's also possible the aircraft had a serious malfunction. (After all, another Su-something crashed on a building in another town.) There were some stories that this one was supposed to drop glide bomb(s), but the glide mechanism failed. But that looks even less credible now, unless they had a problem with an entire batch of those wing/glide kits. However, I would not hold my breath for any investigation results to be made public in any case.

Comment: In fact there were two crashes on buildings, in October, a few days apart.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Yeysk_military_aircraft_crash ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Irkutsk_military_aircraft_crash

Comment: This answer might not be correct, but it is a VERY good answer. Thank you "Be Brave Like Ukraine".

My quick take on this incident is "not militarily significant": I will change my mind if such incidents become a trend.

Comment: I just read there was a 3rd bomb found. An emerjency jettison (and an accidental detonation of one of the bombs) seems to be more probable with this information, instead of deliberately dropping 3 bombs with two of them being duds.